# Monitor change of checkbox, but only made by user, not code. jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Note: i have considered using .click( ) but not sure if this is just good enough.
Changes in the UI drive different UI elements.
I have a checkbox that might turn true or false depending on various states.

The checkbox reflects a data structure in the server. And it is in a group that is observing a few kinds of similar objects. When the user picks a different kind of object, the state changes in the ui. The checkbox included.

So, depending on the state from the server, I have to alter the checkbox sometimes.

I need to inform the server about the checkbox change but only if the user toggled it. Not when the user picked a different object, and the ui changed the checkbox (to reflect the state)
I thought using .change() but it is fired no matter what drove the change.
The checkbox is actually a bootstrap toggle.
Will .click() be sufficient? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code, it's difficult to say anything with certainty. However, the `click()` should be sufficient for what you're describing. The handler will be called whenever a mouse click or keyboard "click" happens on that checkbox/element. I don't know how you're changing the checkbox when you update the UI, assuming you're changing the DOM or modifying the `checked` property directly, you should be fine.

Here's a simple demonstration:

https://jsfiddle.net/j0oeLwh9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.checkbox1').click(function() {
    $('.log').append('<p>click</p>');
  });

  // This causes the `input` click listener to fire
  $('.button1').click(function() {
    $('input').click();
  });

  // This will not fire the `input` click listener
  $('.button2').click(function() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox1')[0];
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  });

});

<div>
  <p><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" />Click Me</label></p>
  <p>Try clicking anywhere in the white area, then using the keybard tab key to focus the checkbox</p>
  <p><button class="button1">Fires Listener</button></p>
  <p><button class="button2">Does Not Fire Listener</button></p>
</div>

<div class="log"></div>
```